# kdb select only one row for each minute

Tags: kdb, qpython

i have some records on kdb, as you see we have 10 row for time: `"8:33"` and 19 row for time `"8:34"` and some other row for time `"8:35"`.

now, how can i select only one row for each group of minute?
for example final result should be like this:  ( only one row which have older second should be chosen for final result)

result should be:

```
9  2022-04-15 08:33:59.453   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
28 2022-04-15 08:34:45.511  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
43 2022-04-15 08:35:33.451  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
```

my kdb:

```
0  2022-04-15 08:33:52.514  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
1  2022-04-15 08:33:56.459   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
2  2022-04-15 08:33:58.465  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
3  2022-04-15 08:33:58.847  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
4  2022-04-15 08:33:58.848   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
5  2022-04-15 08:33:58.849  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
6  2022-04-15 08:33:58.849  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
7  2022-04-15 08:33:59.262  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
8  2022-04-15 08:33:59.262  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
9  2022-04-15 08:33:59.453   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
10 2022-04-15 08:34:02.057   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
11 2022-04-15 08:34:02.387  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
12 2022-04-15 08:34:02.388  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
13 2022-04-15 08:34:03.086   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
14 2022-04-15 08:34:06.176   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
15 2022-04-15 08:34:11.061   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
16 2022-04-15 08:34:14.330   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
17 2022-04-15 08:34:15.381   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
18 2022-04-15 08:34:24.464   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
19 2022-04-15 08:34:26.146  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
20 2022-04-15 08:34:26.394   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
21 2022-04-15 08:34:26.571  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
22 2022-04-15 08:34:27.175  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
23 2022-04-15 08:34:27.654   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
24 2022-04-15 08:34:28.537   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
25 2022-04-15 08:34:30.264  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
26 2022-04-15 08:34:38.094  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
27 2022-04-15 08:34:41.202  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
28 2022-04-15 08:34:45.511  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
29 2022-04-15 08:35:02.625   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
30 2022-04-15 08:35:04.008   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
31 2022-04-15 08:35:06.377  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
32 2022-04-15 08:35:23.843  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
33 2022-04-15 08:35:23.845  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
34 2022-04-15 08:35:23.845  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
35 2022-04-15 08:35:23.845  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
36 2022-04-15 08:35:23.845  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
37 2022-04-15 08:35:23.845  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
38 2022-04-15 08:35:26.986  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
39 2022-04-15 08:35:31.219   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
40 2022-04-15 08:35:31.221   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
41 2022-04-15 08:35:31.897   b'buy'  b'ETH-USDT'
42 2022-04-15 08:35:31.898  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
43 2022-04-15 08:35:33.451  b'sell'  b'ETH-USDT'
```

Comment: Did you try to use the [xgroup](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/xgroup/) and [max](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/max/) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```
value select by b.minute from t
```

where `b` is your column of timestamps and `t` is your table.

Example:

```
q)show t:([]a:til 10; b:.z.p-00:04 00:04 00:04 00:03 00:03 00:03 00:01 00:00 00:00 00:00; c:10?`3 )
a b                             c
-----------------------------------
0 2022.04.15D09:09:11.100787000 ndd
1 2022.04.15D09:09:11.100787000 hpb
2 2022.04.15D09:09:11.100787000 ihm
3 2022.04.15D09:10:11.100787000 fph
4 2022.04.15D09:10:11.100787000 gmg
5 2022.04.15D09:10:11.100787000 kpf
6 2022.04.15D09:12:11.100787000 ecp
7 2022.04.15D09:13:11.100787000 mai
8 2022.04.15D09:13:11.100787000 bof
9 2022.04.15D09:13:11.100787000 mno
q)select by b.minute from t
minute| a b                             c
------| -----------------------------------
09:09 | 2 2022.04.15D09:09:11.100787000 ihm
09:10 | 5 2022.04.15D09:10:11.100787000 kpf
09:12 | 6 2022.04.15D09:12:11.100787000 ecp
09:13 | 9 2022.04.15D09:13:11.100787000 mno
q)value select by b.minute from t
a b                             c
-----------------------------------
2 2022.04.15D09:09:11.100787000 ihm
5 2022.04.15D09:10:11.100787000 kpf
6 2022.04.15D09:12:11.100787000 ecp
9 2022.04.15D09:13:11.100787000 mno
```

Comment: what about a custom minute? for example if i want to select and get only one row for each 2 minute or 5 minute ?

Comment: You'd then need to use [xbar](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/xbar/) to round each time to your required minute interval, for example `select by 2 xbar b.minute from t`. NB for Kyle's example, the table must be pre-sorted ascendingly to obtain the last record in a given bucket using by